# How to use a variable in group by clause in dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to have a dynamic SQL statement which should do aggregations on the columns which will pass to it as variables. But I got the below error.

The pseudo code is as follow:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @params nvarchar(max)

SET @sql = N'SELECT @Input1, @Input2, COUNT(ID) FROM Customers GROUP BY @Input1, @Input2'
SET @params = N'@Input1 nvarchar(225), @Input2 nvarchar(255)'

sp_executesql @sql, @params, @Input1 'Name', @Input2 'Age'
```

And the error is as bellow:

> "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not
> an outer reference."

I don't really get the cause of this error, so any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Check your output without the group by clause.

Comment: That is not how parameter works in `sp_executesql`. It is not a variable substitution for column name. The parameters are for values.

Comment: @Squirrel So you mean that I cannot substitute the column names in sp_executesql ?

Comment: Yes. You can't. Parameters are not for column substitution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options, sqlcmd allows substitution for things like column names, or you need to build up the query dynamically. Ensure you check the inputs to avoid sql injection.

```
SET @sql = N'SELECT ' + @Input1 + ', ' + @Input2 + ', COUNT(ID) FROM Customers GROUP BY ' + @Input1 + ', ' + @Input2;
```